# Qt creator build fail

Tags: build, qt4

I have problem with building in Qt4 creator. I have some created projects and I want take it to different folder.

I already fail in this:
[image]

If I understand well, it is a problem somewhere in the settings of the project. Perhaps you hold the folder where it was created.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's probably because of the space in your path: "zkouska 15.5.2012"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know where he could be a problem. In that folder, it really is, is there anything missing.

Comment: @avalagne, try to remove accentuated characters from the path.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really was a problem in the gap.